# Ho to access the Action from WebApiController with many actions and same parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I can't see the trouble, i have the ApiController with many actions, when i try to do request to one of action i have the following exception. Thanks in advance

//Angular script

```
var app = angular.module('app');
app.factory('userRepository', function ($http) {

    var defaultUrl = 'api/UsersApi';

    return {

      addUserToRole: function (data) {
              return $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: defaultUrl + '/' + 'AddUserToRole',
                data: {
                    RoleId: data.RoleId,
                    UserId: data.User.UserId
                }
            });
        }
    }
});



//Api controller
public class UsersApiController : ApiController
    {
        UserRepository uRep;
        RoleRepository rRep;

        [Authorize]
        [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage AddUserToRole(Int32 RoleId, Int32 UserId)
        {
            try
            {
                uRep = new UserRepository();
                uRep.AddUserToRole(UserId, RoleId);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            }
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
    }
}

  //Route configuration
    public static class WebApiConfig
        {
            public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
            {
                config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                   name: "DefaultApi1",
                   routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                   defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

                config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                    name: "DefaultApi2",
                    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"
                                  );
            }
        }
```

After request i have the result:

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.


The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'.

if i change HttpPost to HttpGet appears the following error occurs

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.


No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI '/api/UsersApi/AddUserToRole'.


No action was found on the controller 'UsersApi' that matches the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your addUserToRole function inside your service, instead of setting data with the post set `params`:

```
params: {RoleId: data.RoleId,UserId: data.User.UserId}
```

Also, check your Web API route config to make sure you're allowing multiple requests with the same HTTP method to one controller, do this by including the action name inside your route config.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
   name: "DefaultApi",
   routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
   defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```